# ASCX inline DIV styles?

Tags: html

In the Visual Studio the CSS file has this. I am trying to use an inline code to float these 2 boxes side by side and not alter the actual CSS file if possible. In the ASCX file I have the code as:-

```
 <h2 class="QuickLinks">
                    Build Release Notes</h2>
                <div class="QuickLinks">
    <p> There is a list of very long law statutory codes but putting this as a test only </p>
    <div>

    <h2 class="QuickLinks">
                   Supplemental Release Notes</h2>
                <div class="QuickLinks">
    <p> here is a list of very long law statutory codes/ links and pdf links but putting this as a test only </p>
    </div>
```

css file (sample) there are 100s of settings but I found this:

```
    div#MainContent h2.QuickLinks, div#MainContent h2.QuickLinks a:link, div#MainContent h2.QuickLinks a:visited, div#MainContent h2.QuickLinks a:hover, div#MainContent h2.QuickLinks a:visited, div#MainContent h2.QuickLinks a:hover {
        background-image: url(images/mc/mc_03.jpg);
        background-color: #b0b0b0;
        color: #000;
    }

    div#MainContent div.QuickLinks {
        border: 2px solid #b0b0b0;
        border-top: none;

    }
```

Comment: I added this:<div class="QuickLinks" style="float:right"> on the supplemental Release notes but it does not float too well. Advise?

Comment: You'll need to add a little more code (e.g. what are these elements contained in?) and perhaps a description of what you want to the page to look like--it's very difficult to know from what's written.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap each section in a container, and then either float the containers or give them display of inline-block to get them to sit side-by-side.

HTML:

```
<div class="QuickLinks-Container" style="float:left;width:48%;">
    <h2 class="QuickLinks">Build Release Notes</h2>
    <div class="QuickLinks">
        <p>There is a list of very long law statutory codes but putting this as a test only</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="QuickLinks-Container" style="float:left;width:48%;">
    <h2 class="QuickLinks">Supplemental Release Notes</h2>
    <div class="QuickLinks">
        <p>here is a list of very long law statutory codes/ links and pdf links but putting this as a test only</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xupxf3um/

Comment: Now it looks a little off  https://www.flickr.com/photos/63296411@N08/15417043780/.

Comment: You've likely got other CSS affecting each of these elements, and without seeing all the relevent HTML and CSS its difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual Code. I did not reference all those links and docs. I am unable to see why it does not float as 2 separate boxes on the top.

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="KnowledgeBase.ascx.cs" Inherits="Control_KnowledgeBase" %>
        
        
        
            
            
            
                System Knowledge Base
            
                
                        Home I Customer Care 
                        I Field Customer Care 
                        I  Logout

```
<h2 class="Billboard">
            General System Information</h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                80 Links and Documents
            </p>
        </div>

        <h2 class="QuickLinks">
            Build Release Notes</h2>
        <div class="QuickLinks"style="float:left;width:48%;">

                <p>
             120 Links and Documents

                </p>

            </div>

        </div>


        <h2 class="QuickLinks">
            Supplemental Release Notes</h2>
        <div class="QuickLinks"style="float:left;width:48%;">

                <p>

10 Link and Documents

                </p>
             </div>


        <h2 class="Billboard">
            TFACTS Customer Care</h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                10 Link and Documents
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2 class="Billboard">
            Reference Materials and Storyboards
        </h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                250 Links and documents
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    </div>

    <!-- CLOSES THE MAIN CONTENT DIV -->
```